# How to define odd and even of two a list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to take the elements of a list and put them into two seperate lists of odd and evens in haskell. Here is what I have so far.

```
classEvenOdd :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
classEvenOdd []     = ([] , [])
classEvenOdd (x:xs) =  (even [xs] | odd [xs])
```

The error is as follows:

```
ERROR "new_1.hs":62 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : classEvenOdd
*** Type           : [Int] -> [a]
*** Does not match : [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
```

Comment: From what you wrote, I think it's pretty clear you didn't understand the basics of Haskell. This exercise is about recursion, which is probably beyond your current level. I'd suggest you start with easier exercises, possibly following an Haskell tutorial such as [LYAH].(http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting stems from the line:

```
classEvenOdd [] = []
```

This snippet, on it's own, has the type

```
classEvenOdd :: [a] -> [a]
```

which is not the type you stated (`classEvenOdd :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])`). Your base case is solved by changing the type to:
`classEvenOdd [] = ([], [])`.

However, there is an additional error in your code, even once this issue has been solved. You do not keep the `x` value at the head of your list, so once any syntax issues have been solved (as the syntax in the latter snippet looks unfamiliar to me) you will always end up with empty lists!

You should either keep a partial result and continue passing that down as you check each element of your input list, or you should assume the completion of the sub-list `xs` and then add the result to the correct element of the tuple.

This second approach would look like this:

```
classEvenOdd :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
classEvenOdd [] = ([], [])
classEvenOdd (x:xs) = let (evens, odds) = classEvenOdd xs in if even x 
                      then (x:evens, odds) 
                      else (evens, x:odds)
```

However, this approach will leak space (at least without optimisations turned on) due to relying on the completed value at every stage.

A better approach is to carry the partial result as an extra parameter:

```
classEvenOdd :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
classEvenOdd [] = ([], [])
classEvenOdd x = go ([], []) x
    where go (e,o) (x:xs) = if even x 
                            then go xs (x:e, o)
                            else go xs (e, x:o)
          go (e,o) [] = (e, o)
```

Comment: I think your go function is missing the terminating case for `go [] acc = acc`

Comment: and you mixed up the parameters in the call `classEvenOdd x` should be `classEvenOdd x = go x ([],[])`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure how your code works but I'll work you through my approach to making the function. When I thought about it I thought about doing this:

```
classEvenOdd :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
classEvenOdd xs = (filter odd xs, filter even xs)
```

But that requires the list to be filtered through twice and thus double the time taken to execute*. So we want to define a function over the list that sorts it into the two lists. This sounds like we want a list of Eithers (`[Either Int Int]`). The list can then be converted into the tuple (`([Int],[Int])`) using [partitionEithers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:partitionEithers) ().

```
import Data.Either

classEvenOdd' :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
classEvenOdd' xs = partitionEithers (map eitherEvenOdd xs)

eitherEvenOdd :: Int -> Either Int Int
eitherEvenOdd i
 | even i = Right i
 | odd i  = Left i
```

This can also be done [point free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming)

```
import Data.Either

classEvenOdd' :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
classEvenOdd' = partitionEithers.(map eitherEvenOdd)

eitherEvenOdd :: Int -> Either Int Int
eitherEvenOdd i
 | even i = Right i
 | odd i  = Left i
```

*Subject to non-strictness

Comment: `classEvenOdd :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
classEvenOdd []     = ([], [])
 classEvenOdd (x:xs) 
 | isEven x = ( x:(fst (classEvenOdd xs)) , snd (classEvenOdd xs))
 | otherwise =  ( x: (snd ( classEvenOdd xs)), fst (classEvenOdd xs))`
   I have done his but still keep getting the error :     Undefined variable "isEven"

Comment: I have go it thanks everyone  `isEven, isOdd :: Int -> Bool`
`isEven n = (n `mod` 2) == 0`

`isOdd = not . isEven`
 
`classEvenOdd2 :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int]) `
`classEvenOdd2 [] = ([], []) `
`classEvenOdd2 (x:xs) `
         ` | isEven x = ( x:(fst (classEvenOdd xs)) , snd (classEvenOdd xs))` 
         ` | otherwise = ( x: (snd ( classEvenOdd xs)), fst (classEvenOdd xs))`

Comment: @caz `isEven` is not a function. You want just `even`.

Comment: i created a function is even @HEGX64 `isEven, isOdd :: Int -> Bool` `isEven n = (n `mod` 2) == 0`

Comment: Why not simply `classEvenOdd = partition even`? Or with `odd` to have the same order as the approach with `Either`, but the function name and the code in the question suggest that even elements should come first.

Comment: I didn't know about `partition`. That seams a much better way of doing this